# Unable to create hotspot using Gnome/Debian

Tags: debian, gnome, networkmanager

When I try to create hotspot using the Gnome Network Manager, nothing happens after I click on the "Use as hotspot" button.
After googling, I found out it's a bug and a workaround suggested me to do:

```
hostnamectl --pretty set-hostname <Hostname>
```

I did this, and it still does not seem to work for me.
What to do?